# Ubuntu Docker images tags vs Ubuntu release minor number

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Is there a best practice to match an official Ubuntu minor release update (like LTS 18.04.6) to a tag in the docker repository that is in the form "ubuntu:bionic-20210930"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to target LTS release version current build:

- 18.04 or bionic
- 20.04 or focal
- latest

There is no intermediate LTS releases tags, and I don't know why you could need this, but you can target to date based build as 'bionic-20210930' despite there is no correlation table for dates and minor release.

Comment: Thanks Claudio, yeah I know but I need to stick to a fixed set of binaries during the whole development/test process and upgrade only after the process has been concluded. Also I need to tell which is the base image reference and an official minor version would be preferable.

Comment: Ok. As 18.04.6 is current Bionic version, you can use dated build bionic-20210930 as 18.04.6 with confidence.

Comment: Marked as valid as I can't find a better way than relying on the release date.